# ER Modelling List of String Objects for Auditing Purpose Only

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, entity-relationship

For a given **request-id** third-party service generates the following

1. List of Recommendations of type String (typically 5-10 recommendations)
2. List of Treatments of type String (typically 5-10 Treatments)
3. List of Services of type String (typically 5-10 Services)

I need to store this data into my system for **auditing purpose**, so if tomorrow someone want's to get all the above information given a **request-id**, I should be able to give them raw data.

I see there are two ways of doing it.

1. Create 3 tables, for Recommendations, Treatments and Services. Link all the three tables with RequestId. Only for **auditing**, I don't think the above approach is scalable, because for every request, I might end up creating up to 30 rows and also duplicating request-id everywhere.
2. Concatenate the List of Recommendations, Services and Treatments and just dump them into a table. That way I just end up with 1 row with two columns, requestId and Concatenated String.

Second approach is not clean but I am bending towards it from scalability standpoint, can someone propose a better design.

Note: I have thought about logging the data in log files, but I have been asked to persist them into db instead.

Comment: Why not store your Audit entries as XML or JSON format in a single table against the request ID?

Comment: Currently I am getting all the data in String (but in XML Format), Are you suggesting me to first Convert the XML Formatted String to XML File, and then save it as a BLOB in MySQL. It's not a bad approach, I hope its possible with Hibernate, but instead of conversion to file whats wrong if I simply Store the XML Formatted String directly?

Comment: No I didnt say that you convert in into file, since you already have data as XML just store it as BLOB. Yes, Hibernate is capable of handling it.

Comment: Thanks mprabhat, i am saving the object as clob string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to dump the entire XML string into a single column in a table as CLOB, especially because  the data is meant for auditing purpose only.